# Wordpress: Long Words are truncated before sending API Restful

Tags: wordpress, rest

I'm developing a Wordpress Plugin that extends the Built in Wordpress API RESTFUL.

This the problem:

I make a simple SELECT statement:

```html
$sql = "SELECT id, code, description FROM rules";

$data_rules = $this->db->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );

$response = array( "rules" => $data_reglas  );

return rest_ensure_response($response);
```

Everything works great except for this:

- The "code" field is a VARCHAR(150)
- BUT ONLY 46 Characters are sent to our Client's requests

For example: 
- Code: "THIS_IS_A_VERY_LONG_CODE_WITH_MORE_THAT_FORTY_SIX_CHARACTERS" (61 characters long)
- Sent: "THIS_IS_A_VERY_LONG_CODE_WITH_MORE_THAT_FORTY" (Only 46 characters are sent)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is the query returning the full "code" field data?

Comment: The string gets cut here $this->db->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A ). Is the get_results method... is there some kind configuration to allow long words?

Comment: `get_results` shouldn't truncate your results. Try changing the data type of the code field to BLOB and see if it solves your issue.